# Results on passage of limit under integral sign

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, reference-request

Other than the classics (monotone convergence theorem and dominated convergence theorem), what results are there about the passage of limit under the integral sign in expressions like
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} F_n(x+y) \,dx \text{ or } \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} F_n(x+y_n) \,dx \text{?}$$

Comment: i've never understood why we say "under" instead of "through" the integral sign.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a theorem like that (with integration on bounded domains though) useful in the applications to PDE.

> **Strauss Theorem.** Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $(u_n)$ be a sequence of measurable functions from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $(F_n)$ and $(G_n)$ be two sequences of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that
>
> 1. $F_n\circ u_n\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} v$ a.e. in $\Omega$.
> 2. $\displaystyle\int_\Omega|F_n(u_n(x))G_n(u_n(x))|\;dx\leq C$ for all $n$.
> 3. $G_n\to \infty$ as $F_n\to \infty$.
>
> Then $v\in L^1(\Omega)$ and $F_n\circ u_n \overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} v$ strongly in $L^1(\Omega)$. Thus,
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\Omega F_n(u_n(x))\;dx=\int_\Omega \lim_{n\to\infty }F_n(u_n(x))\;dx.$$

*Proof:* Page 30 [here](http://www.dmm.im.ufrj.br/%7Emedeiros/LinkedDocuments/topicosemedp.pdf).